# Why does it keep saying "Syntax error" when I use multiple "if" loops?

Tags: python

I tried to program a "make your own adventure" story with python, and I tried using multiple "if" loops. However, the program keeps saying "syntax error." Can someone tell me why this is happening and state a possible solution?

```py
a = eval(input("Enter 0 to go on the ladder, and 1 to try out you new pair of plunger boots: "))
if a == 1:
    print("You put on the boots and climb on the side of the ship. You put one foot forward, then the next, then you try to take a step.")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("However, the boots won't budge.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("MISSION FAIL")
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("You climb up the ladder.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You see a guard at the top armed with an automatic rifle.")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("You can use the grenade in your pocket, or you can take him out with your pack of C4")
    time.sleep(5)
    b = eval(input("Enter 0 for grenade, 1 for the pack of C4: ")
    if b == 0:
        print("You throw the grenade up.")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("You hear a smack, and you see the grenade coming back down at you.")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("MISSION FAIL")
        print("Mental note: These guards are known for their fast reflexes.")
        time.sleep(3.5)
```

Comment: FWIW, some terminology - 'if' is not a loop.  Loops are 'for' and 'while' - the body of the loop is repeatedly executed, that's the 'looping' part.

Comment: Syntax errors come from the Python compiler, not the development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a missing "**)**" on your b = eval(...) line.

should be

```
b = eval(input(...))
```

and it's

```
b = eval(input(...)
```

Thus, syntax error.

Comment: But also, I'm not sure why you want eval there at all. You should use ```int(input("Enter 0 for grenade, 1 for C4"))```